# Python 3 string slice behavior inconsistent

Tags: python, slice

Wanted an easy way to extract year month and day from a string.
Using Python 3.1.2

Tried this:

```
processdate = "20100818"
print(processdate[0:4])
print(processdate[4:2])
print(processdate[6:2])
```

Results in:

```
...2010
...
...
```

Reread all the string docs, did some searching, can't figure out why it'd be doing this.
I'm sure this is a no brainer that I'm missing somehow, I've just banged my head on this enough today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a slice of [4:2], you're telling Python to start at character index 4 and stop at character index 2. Since 4 > 2, you are already past where you should stop when you start, so the slice is empty.

Did you want the fourth and fifth characters? Then you want [4:6] instead.

Comment: Ah somewhere along the way I got the impression that 4:2 was start char 4 length of 2 not start char 4 to char 2

Like I said, it was a bonehead thing I just missed along the way.
Thanks.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer to give credit to @kindall! :)

Comment: Or mark mine as correct because I actually fixed the code - and answered first.

Comment: "answered first" is never a reason to mark one item a solution over another; the person who answered second probably put more thought into the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is with [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime)!

```
print( strptime( ..., "%Y%m%d" ) )
```

Comment: Oh lookie there. This could be useful. TY

Answer (score 2):

```
processdate = "20100818" 
print(processdate[0:4]) # year
print(processdate[4:6]) # month
print(processdate[6:8]) # date
```